# Why the validation not running or doing it wrong?

Tags: java, spring-boot

`Library` model

```
package models;

// imports ...

public class Library implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1687396631694947561L;

    private Integer id;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Library name is required.")
    private String name;
    
    // Other fields.
    
    public Library()
    {
        
    }
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    // Other accessors.
}
```

`ValidationResponse` to send the validation result to the client.

```
package responses;

import java.util.Map;

public class ValidationResponse {
    private boolean validated;
    private Map<String, String> errorMessages;
 
    public boolean isValidated() {
        return validated;
    }
 
    public void setValidated(boolean validated) {
        this.validated = validated;
    }
 
    public void setErrorMessages(Map<String, String> errorMessages) {
        this.errorMessages = errorMessages;
    }
 
    public Map<String, String> getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

`LibraryController`

```
package controllers;

// Imports ...

@Controller
public class LibraryController {
    // Some fields ...
    // Some methods ...
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/libraries/create", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})  
    @ResponseBody
    private ValidationResponse create(@Valid @ModelAttribute models.Library library, BindingResult result)   
    {  
        ValidationResponse response = new ValidationResponse();
         
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            Map<String, String> errors = result.getFieldErrors().stream()
                    .collect(
                            Collectors.toMap(FieldError::getField, FieldError::getDefaultMessage)
                    );
 
            response.setValidated(false);
            response.setErrorMessages(errors);
        } else {
            response.setValidated(true);
            // creating a record in the database
        }
        
        return response;
    } 
}
```

When sending an ajax request to a `/libraries/create` in which the value of the name is empty, then a `ValidationResponse.isValidated` comes with the value `true`, and a record is created in the database with an empty name. Why the validation not running or doing it wrong?

Comment: first thing, ValidationResponse() should be public. Your codeis looking good, still if its not working , try @Component ValidationResponse Dto.

Comment: @SauriBabu Dto? Do I have to add `@Component` annotation to `ValidationResponse`? I don't think the problem is in the `ValidationResponse` class but I made the edits you indicated. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to replace "@NotEmpty" annotation to "@NotBlank" annotation
Please see the following example:

```
@NotBlank(message = "Library name is required.")
private String name;
```